# (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, afnetworking-2

I've been getting the following error when using the GET method to retrieve a file from a server:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x16e81ed0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

I've tried a number of different things and I believe it could be something to do with the JSON format on the file that I'm trying to get.

Here is the code I've been using:

```
_username = @"JonDoe";
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"username" : _username};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];

[manager GET:@"http://.........."
  parameters:parameters
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

My POST method works fine. I just can't seem to fix this issue with the GET. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: we cant possibly help you without seeing the actual GET request, or at least the value of `_username`. the docs also say that the failure block is executed when the response cannot be parsed, so check the reply as well.

Comment: ok so now how about `operation.response`?

Comment: operation.responseSerializationError = error: summary string parsing error

Comment: no, i meant the actual response... http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html#//api/name/response

Comment: or whatever way you can get the actual http response head+body. not super familiar with this particular API.

Comment: NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString) gives--> error: p_large_jldr_475f00025cc22d0e.jpg

Comment: certainly doesnt look like json to me so I would guess that is your problem. in other words, the GET request is successful, but the response cannot be decoded as json (as you have requested by using `AFJSONResponseSerializer`)

Comment: Apologies. This is the error you were requesting:   error: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x16588b40> { URL: http://69.91.198.44:8080/GeodatabaseServer/File?username=liubang } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 33;
    Date = "Tue, 23 Sep 2014 03:58:18 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
} }

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Judging by the discussion in the comments it appears that your GET request is successful (response code 200), but the response body is not valid JSON (nor a JSON fragment) as you have requested by your use of `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. A basic `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` can be used for responses that are not JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your help Brad. I am new to JSON. If I upload a file as JSON to the Apache server, when I do a request to GET should it not be a valid JSON, or could it be altered by the server?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not sure what you are asking. you cannot upload anything via GET. the error you are getting is due to the server *response* to your GET request, not your GET request itself. GET requests are not typically json either. responses for a server can be anything at all.

Comment: No I meant I had uploaded using the POST method where I used JSON. So if I upload using JSON I can download with a different serializer?

Comment: @Jonathan the `responseSerializer` should be selected based on the type of *response* data you expect from the server. it has nothing to do with what you are posting.

Comment: I switched it to the AFHTTPResponseSerializer and appears to be working. I just need to test it when I get a chance. Thanks Brad.

Comment: Hello,@Brad Allred , but i am not using AFHTTPResponseSerializer for Calling WebService , i am using defualt NSJsonSerialization . then what is the change in that method for this particular error?..... Please Help me ASAP.

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya that is the problem, you _can't_ use `NSJsonSerialization` for payloads that are _not_ JSON. its that simple. Use `AFJSONResponseSerializer` or something more appropriate instead.

Comment: I meant `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that you have a valid response from server but your response is not a valid format in JSON, probably because you have carachters in front of first { .
Please try this: Put the same URL address manually in your browser and you will see the culprit in the response. Hope it helped.

Answer (score -2):

Hey guys this is what I found to be my issue: I was calling Alamofire via a function to Authenticate Users: I used the function "Login User" With the parameters that would be called from the "body"(email: String, password: String)  That would be passed

my errr was exactly:

optional(alamofire.aferror.responseserializationfailed(alamofire.aferror.responseserializationfailurereason.jsonserializationfailed(error domain=nscocoaerrordomain code=3840 "invalid value around character 0." userinfo={nsdebugdescription=invalid value around character 0

character 0 is the key here: meaning the the call for the "email" was not matching the parameters: See the code below

func loginUser(email: String, password: String, completed: @escaping downloadComplete) {
        let lowerCasedEmail = email.lowercased()

```
    let header = [
        "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ]
    let body: [String: Any] = [
        "email": lowerCasedEmail,
        "password": password
    ]

    Alamofire.request(LOGIN_USER, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.error == nil {

            if let data = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                if let email = data["user"] as? String {
                    self.userEmail = email
                    print(self.userEmail)
                }
                if let token = data["token"] as? String {
                    self.token_Key = token
                    print(self.token_Key)
                }
```

"email" in function parameters must match the let "email" when parsing then it will work..I no longer got the error...And character 0 was the "email" in the "body" parameter for the Alamofire request:

Hope this helps