# API with text/plain response failed with 'unacceptable content-type'

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I'm trying to perform a `GET` request that responses with '`text/plain`'

The request failed with error "unacceptable content-type: text/plain".

so I set the `AcceptableContentType` to `"text/plain"`  and created a responseSerializer`with`NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`.

But the request Also failed with error .

> NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840" : "Invalid value around character 0."

```
      NSString *requestUrl = [NSString
                          stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kServerURL,myURL];

  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

  manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
      serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

  [manager.responseSerializer
      setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
  [manager GET:requestUrl
      parameters:nil
      progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
```

Comment: hide both manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
      serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

  [manager.responseSerializer
      setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];  and add  manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

Comment: without them it failed with 'JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set'
So I added them.

Comment: and without  [manager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"] 
it failed with "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain"

Comment: can you update the question once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) AFNetworking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986129/cocoa-error-3840-invalid-value-around-character-0-afnetworking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this place

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
  serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[manager.responseSerializer
  setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
```

use

```
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
```